# In Firebase Android Development, what does the "isNewUser" method refer to exactly?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

in the following code:

```
private val auth: FirebaseAuth

val authResult = auth.signInWithCredential(googleCredential).await()
val isNewUser = authResult.additionalUserInfo?.isNewUser ?: false
```

What does the isNewUser variable tell us? Does it tell us that the user is new to my app/my app's firestore database? Or, does it tell us whether the user is new to firestore authentication in general?  More specifically, can this variable be used to check if the user exists in my app's firestore database?

I found this code snippet in an article that explains how to implement firestore in jetpack compose.  My interpretation of the code that the author wrote implies that this value can be used to check if the user is new to my app (in the article, the author calls a method that adds the user to their firestore database if and only if the isNewUser value returns false).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `isNewUser` is `true`, that means the user has logged in to your application ("Firebase Project") for the first time i.e. created a new account with Google or any OAuth provider. This is useful because unlike email password authentication that has separate `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` and `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`, OAuth providers just have `signInWithCredential()` (or popup/redirect on web).

Firebase Authentication is a different product and has nothing to do with Firestore. They can be used individually.

Comment: If a user uses google one tap sign-in to sign-in to a different app that also uses firebase/firestore, and then comes to my app and also does a one tap sign-in with their same google account to access my firestore, then isNewUser will still be false?

Comment: @ChristopherRomano "different app" as in? If you are using same Firebase project then yes, it'll be false.

Comment: different app meaning someone else's app that is completely unrelated to mine (a different firebase project)

Comment: Then it'll be true if its uses a different Firebase project and this user has not already used the Google Account there.

Comment: they have used the same google account there, and they will now use this same account to access my app (there meaning: a different firebase project)

Comment: "the user has logged in to your application for the first time i.e. created a new account with Google or any OAuth provider" That's not entirely correct. The user profile is new in their Firebase **project**, but (in the case of social providers) doesn't have to be (and typically isn't) new to the OAuth provider.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen this seems to be the key piece of info to clarify the answer. Specifically: the isNewUser variable tells us that the user is new to this, and only this, Firebase project, regardless of whether or not their account (in this example google account) is new or not to the OAuth provider, meaning they could have used their same google account to access another firebase project and would still be considered a new user when accessing my firebase project for the first time.  thank you both for the help.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I should've highlighted that in the answer instead of discussing in the comments.